# Example of send data such as sales order etc. FROM SugarCRM to an external webservice

Tags: sugarcrm

There are plenty of examples of sending data to SugarCRM via a web-service, but much harder to find good examples of outbound from SugarCRM to say create a new order in an accounting system, etc.

Can anyone point me to a few examples of sending FROM SugarCRM using REST or any similar method please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lightweight way to do this would be via an after_save logic hook calling out via web services to do this; we have a simple API for doing REST calls now in Sugar 6.5

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/05/11/new-for-sugar-6-5-sugarhttpclient/

A more robust method however is leveraging the same Connectors API that we deliver the integrations with Facebook, Twitter, WebEx, InsideView, Google, and other services. Here's some examples of this done in the wild

http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/connect-external-application-80706/#post280938